# Check for all requests to be done

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request-promise

I am currently working on a scraper that is fetching multiple URI's asynchronously.
My problem is, that I want to await all responses to be processed, but I do not know how to find out when every is processed.

The last log with "Done!" does run even before the responses have come back.

Thanks for helping
Xaver :)

````
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

//The function
function getData(arr) {


    // Using loop to fetch every adress
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {



        //Setting my options
    let opt = {
        method: 'GET',
        //Inserting index into url to get different site every loop
        uri: `https://example.de/${i}`,
        headers: {
            Referer: 'example.de',
        },
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
        //Loading jquery/cherrio
        transform: function (body) {
            return cheerio.load(body);
        }
    };

    //running the request
    rp(opt)
    .then(($) => {
        console.log('Success fetching Data of : ' + arr[i])
        console.log('Now formatting!')


        //formatting my data ...


    })

    .catch((err => {
        //err handling
        console.error(err.message)
        console.info(`Retrying in ${errDelay / 1000}sec`)
        setTimeout(() => {
            rp(opt)
        }, errDelay);
    }))



}

//This should run after every request is formatted but currently it runs before the requests are done BUT IT DOESN'T
console.log('Done!')


}

getData()```
````

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Thanks for helping i already tried using promises but i dont know how to create then when using an for loop

Comment: Collect the promises in an array, then use `Promise.all` on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is what you want.

```js
Promise.all(arr.map((_,i)=>{
    //Setting my options
    let opt = {
        method: 'GET',
        //Inserting index into url to get different site every loop
        uri: `https://example.de/${i}`,
        headers: {
            Referer: 'example.de',
        },
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
        //Loading jquery/cherrio
        transform: function (body) {
            return cheerio.load(body);
        }
    };

    //running the request
    return rp(opt)
    .then(($) => {
        console.log('Success fetching Data of : ' + arr[i])
        console.log('Now formatting!')


        //formatting my data ...

    })
    .catch((err => {
        //err handling
        console.error(err.message)
        console.info(`Retrying in ${errDelay / 1000}sec`)
        setTimeout(() => {
            rp(opt)
        }, errDelay);
    }))
}).then(()=> console.log('done'))
```

Comment: `
        setTimeout(() => {
            rp(opt)
        }, errDelay);
`

Setting this timeout will break the promise chain though

Answer (score 0):

You can use async await with a try catch block to handle errors.

[MDN documentation on async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

```
async function getData(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let opt = {
      method: 'GET',
      uri: `https://example.de/${i}`,
      headers: {
        Referer: 'example.de',
      },
      resolveWithFullResponse: true,
      transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
      }
    };

    try {
      const response = await rp(opt);
      console.log('Success fetching Data of : ' + arr[i])
      console.log('Now formatting!')
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error(err.message)
      console.info(`Retrying in ${errDelay / 1000}sec`)
      setTimeout(() => {
      rp(opt)
      }, errDelay);
    }
  }
}
```